# how to embed C code in python program?

Tags: python, c, raw-sockets

i want to write a program using multi-threading, raw sockets, to scan the ports in python
i have a C code for injection of raw socket. i want to perform a ACK scan so need a raw socket.

So please help me.

thank you

Comment: Step 1.  Search.  Step 2.  Read.  Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+c  Also, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20c%2b%2b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out [Cython](http://www.cython.org/). It makes it very easy to wrap C code.

This is adapted from the [documentation on calling external C functions](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html):

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double sin(double)

def pysin(x):
    return sin(x)
```

You could then call `pysin` from the compiled module like a normal Python module.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with [boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), which provides even cleaner wrappers. If you dislike the idea of using C++, then Cython is a good alternative.